# Return many variables in Python without dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, return

I have a function `compute_params()` which computes many variables that I want to use in another function, say `main_func()`. For the moment, my code is similar to:

```
def compute_params(i):
    a = i/2
    b = a + 2.
    c = 2*a/b - 1.
    d = a + b + c
    e = ((a + 1.)**2 - d)/c
    # ...and so on with more complex computations and more variables.

    return a, b, c, d, e

def main_func(imax):
    for i in range(imax):
        a, b, c, d, e = compute_params(i)
        # Do something with a, b, c, ...
```

My questions are:

- Considering speed issues, is it a problem to return and get 5, 10 variables (or even more in my real life function)?
- If the answer to the first question is yes, how to simply do that with a dictionary or something similar, taking into account that I need to keep the real variables names in `main_func()` (to put them in big equations)?

NB: just to understand why I want to do that, my function `compute_params()` is used at different places in my code, that's why its content is not directly included in `main_func()`.

**Edit** to answer several suggestions I have had: I would like to avoid classes or dictionaries because (1) the only thing my variables have in common is being useful in the same equation, thus there is no logical reason for grouping them in an object and, above all (2) since these coefficients appear hundreds of times in complex equations that already are painful to read, I want to avoid things like `params.a + params.b/params.c` where I currently and simply write `a + b/c`.

Comment: Strictly speaking you do not return multiple values but one `tuple`.

Comment: Easily as a tuple return (a, b, c...)

Comment: Too many parameters and/or return values is generally considered a code smell - could you encapsulate those parameters in something else (including, yes, a dictionary)?

Comment: @Matthias I am aware of this subtlety but unless there is a way of really returning several values in a function in Python, I guess it's reasonable not to make the distinction between returning multiple variables and returning one tuple.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I added a point in my question to answer this suggestion (I expressed the same idea in my first comment of your answer).

Comment: @Falken: Well you can call the same function with `foo, bar = do_something()` or `baz = do_something()`. In the first case you have tuple unpacking, in the second case you get the whole tuple as one value.

Answer (score 0):

By itself there isn't a speed issue with this. If this code is inside a tight loop, the system runs too slowly for your needs, you have used a profiler and found out that the problem is here, then there might be. It's not at all the first place I would look for speed improvements.

That said: this is unreadable code. You need better variable names, and passing along a large number of variables without more structure than that is a sign of bad code. "compute_params" is also pretty meaningless by itself; what kind of params?

Don't these variables *mean* something? Can't they be grouped together into one or a small number of *classes*?

I think you'll find that if you can group some of them together into a well named class, several of the computations you want to do will turn out to fit naturally as methods of that class. But at least, you'd be able to just hand around the class instance instead of an unwieldy list of variables that you have to repeat everywhere.

Comment: Well, actually the code in the question is **just an example**. I am not sure that if I copy-paste the real code I am using, it will help people much. The variables I used are coefficients used to compute other coefficients in different matrices that define a 8-th order system + boundary conditions of a physical system.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like to pass around many variables, you could try to work with a `namedtuple`. Then you only have to pass around that namedtuple and can still address the variables nicely without unpacking a list:

```
from collections import namedtuple
variables = namedtuple('variables', ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
var = variables(1,2,3,4,5)
var.a # 1
var.b # 5
```

Comment: That's a nice suggestion in this case, I didn't think about it! Anyway, this solution has the same drawback as the ones suggested by jonrsharpe...

Comment: Thank you, you have put me on the rails to the best solution for me finally (see [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25931907/return-many-variables-in-python-without-dictionary/25936977#comment40605339_25933053) to jonrshape)!

Comment: I move back... My "solution" was at least useless, more probably stupid (I did some timing, it was **far more slower** than my initial code!). Still thinking about all of those things now...

Comment: @Falken I think i cannot follow, do you mean the ``namedtuple``-Version (or anything that evolved from that) is faster or slower than passing around the single variables ``a`` to ``e``?

Comment: The namedtuple version is extremely slower (even on my small example code) if I pack everything in a namedtuple, then unpack it in my main function with something like `a, b, c = compute_params(i)` to avoid `var.a`, `var.b` and directly have `a` and `b`.

Comment: @Falken yeh, it is not supposed to be unpacked again but to be used directly as ``var.a`` etc. But I now realize that you want to avoid that. I use named tuples for readabilty and grouping variables. For instance a circle could be represented with ``circle.x circle.y circle.radius``, which is (as much as i can think of it) nice because it is grouped (you pass over the named tuple ``circle`` and very it is readable. However, i see that it is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Given the way your parameters are calculated, one option would be a simple class:

```
class Params(object):

    def __init__(self, i):
        self.a = i / 2.0
        self.b = self.a + 2
        self.c = (2 * (self.a / self.b)) - 1.
        self.d = self.a + self.b + self.c
        self.e = (((self.a + 1) ** 2) - self.d) / self.c
```

You can then pass around a single instance of this class:

```
def main_func(imax):
    for i in range(imax):
        params = Params(i)
        # use e.g. params.a in an equation
```

---

Alternatively, using a dictionary could look something like:

```
def create_params(i):
    params = {'a': i / 2.0}
    params['b'] = params['a'] + 2
    params['c'] = (2 * (params['a'] / params['b'])) - 1
    params['d'] = params['a'] + params['b'] + params['c']
    params['e'] = (((params['a'] + 1) ** 2) - params['d']) / params['c']
    return params
```

This can then be accessed easily by key:

```
def main_func(imax):
    for i in range(imax):
        params = create_params(i)
        # use e.g. params['a'] in an equation
```

or, if you have a function that takes the parameters (or some subset), you can unpack the dictionary straight into it:

```
def func(a, d, **kwargs): # kwargs mops up unused parameters
    # does stuff with a and d
    return result

result = func(**params)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer but that's exactly what I wish I could avoid. The variables are used in somewhat huge equations that are already painful to read and I wanted to avoid writing something like params.a**2/params.b + 1./params.c - params.d rather than a**2/b + 1./c - d...

Comment: @Falken if you encapsulate the sums in functions that take the parameters they need (see `func` at the end of my answer) you can deal with this relatively neatly using dictionary unpacking.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean, I didn't get this point. That's probably the best answer to my question. I will think about it a little bit and test it in my real code and I come back to accept your answer if everything is fine (sorry I can't up vote because of my low reputation :-/ )

Comment: Well... I can't figure out how to make your solution working properly. Could you please modify your answer to give a more complete and working example using **kwargs as a function argument? Something more: you can't use an undefined variable as a dict key, I guess you thought `params['a']` when you wrote `params[a]`, etc.

Comment: @Falken you're right, sorry; I missed the quotes throughout the third code block, and in the comment in the fourth. However, that doesn't change the last - once you have the dictionary, you can unpack it to supply keyword arguments to a function.

Comment: @jonrshape I found the best-suited solution to me, using the ideas you suggested here and namedtuples as Nras suggested. But still no way to "officially" thank you both with up vote, nor to accept my own answer for the moment... Anyway, for me the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you (kind of) asking for macros ?

You might try [karnickel](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/karnickel).

Comment: Interesting, I could need this kind of thing someday, didn't know about it! But for the moment, I finally found a solution, taking the best of several other suggestions.

Answer (score -2):

That is one of the reasons people invented the object-oriented programming, where same variables can be related to a bunch of functions.

Comment: The problem with OOP being that you need to replace short and simple variables names by something like `class_name.a`, `class_name.b`, etc. as I said in other comments, even if you don't really need to group these variables which are only a bunch of useful coefficients, sometimes without obvious relationship.

Comment: by the way, In OOPS object has member variables and member functions.